# ZipArchive ExtractTo() Permission Denied

Tags: php, apache, permissions, centos7, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to extract zip files from a folder into a subfolder. The error I'm recieving is:

```
Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(XXXX): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/update_alerts2.php on line 97
extracted
```

Code :

```
    public function extractFiles($inputDir,$outputDir) {
        $files_to_extract = $this->getFiles($inputDir);
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        foreach ($files_to_extract as $file) {

            echo $file;
            $res = $zip->open($inputDir . $file);
            if ($res) {
                $zip->extractTo($outputDir);
                $zip->deleteName($inputDir . $file);
                $zip->close();
            } else {
                echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
            }
        }   
    }
```

I've tried setting permissions to 777 but I still get the error. What are the possible ways I can fix this issue (I'm using centos7 and apache) ?

Comment: Which permissions did you set? Those of the subfolder or of the ZIP file?

Comment: Both directories have 777 permissions

Comment: Changing the owner of the zip file to the user running Apache